# Selectbox div show / hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know of a simple example of showing / hiding a div when one of two select dropdown options are selected? I'd like to keep it simple and not have to use plugins with the exception of jquery which is already loading.

Comment: You're probably looking for the `.change()` event handler: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I wish people would say why they're giving a -1. It's this a site where you can ask any question?

Comment: Probably because your question lacks specifics -- it's always better to add some code samples so we know exactly what the problem is. Have you read the FAQ? http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the following function which shows the passed element if the dropdown have the values 12 and 22 (you can change it to whatever you need):

```
function showDiv(element, firstDropdown, secondDropdown) {
    firstDropdown.children("option:selected").val() == 12 && secondDropdown.children("option:selected").val() == 22 ? element.show() : element.hide();
}
```

then in jQuery you can write the following:

```
var myElement = $("div");
var myFirstDropdown = $("select#first");
var mySecondDropdown = $("select#second");

$("select").change(function() {
    showDiv(myElement, myFirstDropdown, mySecondDropdown)
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ERS9D/

Comment: i changed the code a bet to work with what I want to do http://jsfiddle.net/hZQaK/2/ but when applying it to my actual webpage I can't get it to run ... I changed the first like to $(document).ready(function showDiv(element, pro2) { is that correct?

Comment: @acctman wrap it with `$(document).ready(function() {//your code here});`

Answer (score 2):

Just use `jQuery.hide()` / `.show()`.

Hook up to selects' `onchange` event and hide/show based on your rules.

```
$('select').change(function(){

   if($(this).val() == 'my value' || $('other select').val() == 'my value')
       $('div').show();
    else
        $('div').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

simply bind the onSelect event to the dropdown so you can show/hide a specific div

```
$('#dropdown').change(function() {
  // show hide your div with $.show/hide
});
```